Does PrimeReact's Editor support highlight.js?
I'm using PrimeReact's Editor component and trying to add syntax highlighting to it. It is based on the Quill library so I tried to use highlight.js lib as the Quill's documentation says:
import hljs from "highlight.js";

// ...

<Editor
    modules={{
        syntax: { hljs }
    }}
    // ...
    onTextChange={(e) => {
        changeSomeStateWith(e.htmlValue ?? "");
    }}
/>

Only one thing has changed in the Editor's view after it. Now I can see a select with some programming languages when I try to add a code block:

Nothing is being highlighted and e.htmlValue now contains the code of the select element.
ChatGPT says I must manipulate DOM to integrate highlight.js in this case. Can I do it without DOM manipulation in React?
